# Derivative of composition of functions (in the process of proving that there is some diffeomorphism)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am trying to follow the proof of the theorem from an online pamphlet of J.M. Lee. ---
If $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $0\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^k\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map with $f(0)=0$ such that $Df(0)$ has rank $k$, then there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, an open neighbourhood $W$ of $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism $g:V\longrightarrow W$ such that $g\circ f:f^{-1}(V)\longrightarrow W$ is of the form $(a^1,...,a^k)\mapsto (a^1,a^2,...,a^k,0,..,0)$.

The proof begins as follows:

Since $Df(0)$ has rank $k$ there is a linear map $A :\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n =
\mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^{n−k}$ such that $A\circ Df (0)$ is of the form $x \mapsto (\alpha (x) , 0)$ for a linear
isomorphism $\alpha : \mathbb{R}^k \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ . I think this is because we look at the matrix of $Df(0)$, only $k$ rows will be independent, we can then get $A$ to make these the first $k$ rows. Is that what it means? But that will directly come by row operations right?

He also says that $A\circ Df (0) = D (A \circ f ) (0)$. How do we get this? I tried getting expressions for both in terms of basis elements, but I did not get the equality.

Any help will be immensely appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya $A$ just kills the vectors in the $n-k$ dimensional subspace which is not spanned by $Df(0)$.
Further $A$ is a linear map and hence $D(A) = A$. So, applying chain rule, $D(A \circ f) = A \circ Df$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful!

Comment: Always welcome.

Comment: I have another doubt, can we choose $A$ to be an isomorphism?